# Cannot convert value of type 'NSNotification.Name' to expected argument type 'NSKeyValueObservingOptions'

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter, here-api

In NMAPositioningManager.h there is this const :

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePositionNotification;
```

And there is my code in swift

```
NotificationCenter.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "positionDidUpdate", options: NSNotification.Name.NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePosition, context: NMAPositioningManager.shared())
```

Inspired from this example in Obj-C:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(positionDidUpdate)
 name:NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePositionNotification
 object:[NMAPositioningManager sharedNMAPositioningManager]];
```

I have an error with the field option :

> NavigationViewController.swift:30:84:
>   Cannot convert value of type 'NSNotification.Name' to expected
>   argument type 'NSKeyValueObservingOptions'

[image]

What i have to type to have my Swift Code working ?

EDIT : using NotificationCenter instead of Notification

Comment: Just to clarify. Your Objective C example uses NSNotificationCenter and your Swift code is using NSNotification. Would you like to use NSNotification or is it NSNotificationCenter you'd like to use?

Comment: In fact, it's NotificationCenter that i have to use. I edit my answer but i have still the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the addObserver.. method on `default` singleton
It should be:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(positionDidUpdate), name: NSNotification.Name.NMAPositioningManagerDidUpdatePosition, object: NMAPositioningManager.shared())
```

Comment: That's it, i have used the bad sentence in "addObserver". Many thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED WITH SWIFT 5.4**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(doThisWhenNotify),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name("notificationKey"),
                                       object: nil)
```